# Existing Java Application: How to add a webinterface?

Tags: java, html, jsp, gwt, web-applications

I have written a Java application, which is based on swing. Now I want to expand my project to an webinterface.
I want to say that I have a database,where all relevant data is stored and so I could write an external webapplication.

I really don't the better approach:

**1.Should I expand the existing project with the ability of a webinterface. But what technology should I use?**

+GWT? The existing project is my backend and I build a new frontend?

+Servlets JSP?

**2.Should I write an external Webapplication, which gets data from the database?** 
-What technology should I use?

At last I have one more question: When I use Servlets and JSP, what's about the design. Is it hard to create good looking JSPs?

So what's the better choice? And what technology should I use?
I hope you can help me!

Regards
Marko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that a swing-application is completly different to a web-application. While a java-application(console, awt, swt, swing) is started using a main-function an web-application is served by an servlet-container like tomcat, jetty, ... So you can't just add an web-frontend to your Swing-App.

If you just want to try-out a bit you could use netbeans and create a new "Web Application"-Project using "Spring MVC". That takes about 5min.
Using JSP is a bit outdated like Struts. For a new web-application i would recommend using one of the following technologies: JSF2, Spring-MVC, Wicket, GWT. Since you got a Swing-Background you should probably go for GWT as you already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: you are welcome. i got no idea why your question was downvoted. beginners have to start at some point, so its not completly wrong to ask experts about  their opinions.

Comment: ChrisKo, by the way I have my next question: Through my external database I could build up my webinterface with pure HTML/ Bootstrap. The second possibility would be gwt or maybe bootstrap-gwt. So what's your opinion: I tend to use gwt, because I don't like using javascript and HTML - so I prefer using java. It would a website with 4-5 different sites and a lot of http requests. Is it the wrong approach to avoid html and to use gwt? Is it to "overkill"?

Comment: Thats sounds like ajax-requests are required in the first place. So it could be smart to keep the server-side small. Maybe a simple servlet which sends queries to the database and transforms the sql-results to json which could be send to the browser. this enables you to concentrate you efforts to the frontend. On the other hand it could be better to use gwt in the long run. maybe your application grows more as expected so gwt, hibernate,... could save you some time later on. also gwt-knowledge has a higher value. You could also take a look at Vaadin to make things even more interesting. ;)

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I will choose gwt. What do you think about the different versions of gwt? What's the "best" one(smartgwt,gwt,bootstrap gwt) ? You helped me a lot !

Comment: I forgot vaadin. SmartGwt or vaadin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information here to really give you definite answers, but some things that might point you in the right direction are:

**Is your application's GUI and backend code roughly separate?** 
If you work on splitting apart the front end from all the services (saving and retrieving data, etc) then you end up with an informal API. From here is very much up to you how you implement the Web facing part. You'll essentially turn your app into 3 parts - a client, a server and a webapp.

**Does it *really* matter what technology you use?**
If this is for fun/learning, pick something new. If you need to do it soon, you're better sticking with what you know. Or maybe there are other requirements on the project? There's almost never a right answer about what to use, it comes down to specifics, knowledge and preference.